# handling error where date selected less than current date

Tags: php, html

I'm a newbie in this php and html. I'm developing a laundry system using php with mysql. right now, users can just enter whatever date they want for pickup and delivery.. for example, today is 10 feb 2018, user key in 9 feb 2018 as pickup. that should not be possible. how do i handle that? my html are

```
<font face="Arial Black">Pickup date:</font>
<input type="date" name="pickupdate">
```

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet is from one of my projects, see if this helps you in anyway:

The HTML Code:

```
<label for="from">From</label> 
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> 

<label for="to">to</label> 
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
```

The Javascript Code:

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for you time.. I just found another simple way to do it.. like this = <input type="date" name="pickupdate" min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
. Is it fine? I tried and seems to be working. I'm just worried it will cause another problem in future..

Comment: Well sorry, not sure on that. If you got it from some good source, it should work.